# "can either lead to X or Y" vs. "can lead to either X or Y": which is correct?

Tags: either-or

Which is correct?

1. This degree of freedom in design ***can either lead to*** energy efficiency or better space utilization of room, or both.
2. This degree of freedom in design ***can lead to either*** energy efficiency or better space utilization of room, or both.

Comment: Why not just say ***can lead to energy efficiency, better space utilization, or both*** to be clear? What does the *either* add to the meaning?

Comment: "either" is here to emphasize that "this design" can sometimes cause A or B depending on the situation. Having both A and B can be a possibility and is not always true.

Comment: @NAASI "either" is usually used to suggest that the possibilities are mutually exclusive. I'd say "can lead to X and/or Y" if they're not exclusive.

Comment: To me, putting the "either" _before_ the "lead to" makes it sound like another verb should follow, e.g. "You should _either_ choose number 2 or omit the 'either'" (notice the two verbs). But as others have said, since you add "or both," using "either" at all is not technically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#2 is correct (or more correct).  #1 is incorrect (or less correct), but it will usually be understood by most listeners as meaning the same thing as #2.

In other words, this answer is a bit pedantic - most people will not notice or care about the difference, in most contexts.

This is correct:

> *This degree of freedom in design can **either lead** to energy efficiency **or lead** to better space utilization.*

(And you could use a different verb in place of the second "*lead to*":  *...can either lead to energy efficiency or **enable** better space utilization.*)

This is also correct:

> *This degree of freedom in design **either can lead** to energy efficiency **or can lead** to better space utilization.*

The positions of *either* and *or* control (at least suggest) their scope.

Comment: Phew! that means I don't need to post a more pedantic answer. Nevertheless, in all those cases, *either* seems to add nothing useful. How would it change either the nature or the likelihood of the outcomes if you left *either* on the shelf?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: *either*...*or* provides a way of scoping effect of the *or*. In other words, it performs grouping. In programming languages that would be done using, for example, parentheses. *either A or B* is generally equivalent to `or (A, B)`, where *A* and *B* can be anything. *either...or...* means *either (...) or (...)*. Without the *either* it can be ambiguous where the grouping starts/ends. So in some cases the *either* is superfluous, but not in general.

Comment: Thanks for the 101 and could you look past that generic lecture and focus on the specific cases here?

In all those cases, neither *either* by itself nor *either / or* in combination  seem to add anything useful… though you might be able to explain how at least one of them does?

Please either accept that it doesn't, or explain how you think it would change either the nature or the likelihood of the outcomes if you left *either* on the shelf

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: Correct; in these particular examples you need not use *either*. There is no possibility of ambiguity without *either*, here.

Comment: Thanks Drew and also I’m sorry; I was concentrating so hard on your answer, I skipped over the original comments where Davo and vanderpn tried to make the same point… but it seemed to bounce off.

What you said was quite right but NAASI banged the nails into his own bed.